# É possível ter um ternário sem o bloco else?

Tags: php, if, else

Existe a possibilidade de cria um if ternário mais simples, digo sem o código do bloco else? como ficaria?

tipo :

```
if($total < 10){
 $total_gerente = 10;
}
```

Pois pelo que sei o ternário tem IF e ELSE. Existe possibilidade de apenas ter o bloco if?

Comment: Não dá para entender o que deseja. Não tem nada de ternário nisto. Explique melhor. Explique com calma, pense antes sobre o problema que quer resolver. Procure dar informações suficientes para as pessoas que não sabem o que você quer fazer poder entender o que quer.

Comment: No ternario caso não queira a parte do else, retorne/deixe uma string vazia ou null.

Comment: isso, não quero o ELSE , mas não quero criar a variável, sacou!

Comment: Ainda não dá para entender, talvez colocar mais partes do código para dar um contexto melhor ajudaria. Ou colocar como quer que fique, mesmo que de um jeito errado.

Comment: Você precisa da parte do else para satisfazer a sintaxe.

Comment: Realmente precisa saber mais sobre seu código, mais pelo que pude entender acredito que o que você quer é `$total_gerente = $total < 10 ? 10 : $total;`, nesse caso de o `$total` for menor do que 10 atribui 10 na variável `$total_gerente` caso contrário atribui o valor da variável `$total`

Answer (score 4):

Traduzindo o código da pergunta para uma condição ternária:

```
$total_gerente = (($total < 10)? 10: null);
```

<sub>Recomendado delimitar a condição com parênteses para evitar problemas com erros de sintaxe.</sub>

Alternativamente, pode fazer assim, caso não queria setar um valor específico na condição contrária

```
($total < 10)? $total_gerente = 10: null;
```

Nota:

Deve estar ciente de que as ações não deve ter mais que uma linha.

Exemplo de código que gera erro

```
($total < 10)? $total_gerente = 10; $outra_var = 'foo': null;
```

Quando houver tal necessidade pode usar técnicas com funções anônimas, mas como isso não faz parte da pergunta, me abstenho e aprofundar mais sobre o assunto.

Comment: Matou cara, vlw

Answer (score 1):

Você pode deixar mais simples de algumas formas:
**1º**

```
if($total < 10) $total_gerente = 10;
```

**2º**

```
  if($total < 10) :
      $total_gerente = 10;
  endif;
```

**3º**

```
if($total < 10) 
    $total_gerente = 10;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O que isto mudou?

Comment: passou de 3 para 1 linha

Comment: Amontoar coisas não deixa nada mais simples. O original dele inclusive estava apresentando em uma linha

Comment: No código inicial é aberto chaves como se fosse ter várias regras dentro do if. como ele só vai atribuir um valor para a variável, com certeza desse modo fica mais simples.

Comment: Simplicidade é outra coisa, isto só economizou digitação.

Comment: Mas mesmo assim não justifica ter feito uma resposta para isso. E de qualquer forma isso não resolve nada. A pergunta continua sem lógica e a única resposta também.

Comment: A 3 opções não são IFs ternários. São sintaxes alternativas. Note que o `if` ternário não declara explicitamente o termo `if()`